# Can I remap WORD or "W" key in VIM normal mode?

Tags: vim

Can I remap `WORD` or `W` key in VIM normal mode? The original `W` traverse text separated with white space. I'd like the motion `W` to be mapped as traversing text-object including `word` and `.`, `-`.

For example:

```
some-object=another.object
```

if I press `viW` on `some-object` I'd like to see `some-object`  selected rather than `some-object=another.object` selected as in the original setup.

Is there a way for me to make this change? Where should I look up in vimdoc?

Comment: `:help 'iskeyword'` to include hyphens and use `w` instead?

Comment: Thank you. It's enlightening!!  This may work under circumstances. Yet I'd like to keep the 'w' as original.

Comment: You could map `W` to update `iskeyword`, apply `w`, and change it back, but I don’t know if there’s overhead involved in setting that option.

Answer (score 0):

You could lookup in vim-help with

```
:h WORD
:h motion
```

I just did this and my guess is, you have to write a function and map it to `W`. I read `:h WORD` (capital letters!) that there is no way to change the standard definition of a "WORD"

Comment: Thank you. That seems it. Do happen to know any script functioning like it?

Comment: Not without digging. You may dig yourself on [vim.org > Scripts](https://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php)